# How can I install pyv8 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, boost, v8, pyv8

I installed the `libv8` and `libboost-all-dev` Ubuntu packages, then ran

```
sudo pip install pyv8
```

And got:

```
building '_PyV8' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/Exception.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/Exception.o

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

src/Exception.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ExceptionTranslator::Construct(PyObject*, boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data*)’:

src/Exception.cpp:207:25: warning: unused variable ‘cpp_err’ [-Wunused-variable]

   CJavascriptException* cpp_err =

                         ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/Context.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/Context.o

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

In file included from src/Context.h:7:0,

                 from src/Context.cpp:1:

src/Wrapper.h: In member function ‘const boost::python::api::object& CJavascriptArray::ArrayIterator::dereference() const’:

src/Wrapper.h:115:66: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

     reference dereference() const { return m_array->GetItem(m_idx); }

                                                                  ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/Engine.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/Engine.o

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

In file included from src/Context.h:7:0,

                 from src/Engine.h:7,

                 from src/Engine.cpp:1:

src/Wrapper.h: In member function ‘const boost::python::api::object& CJavascriptArray::ArrayIterator::dereference() const’:

src/Wrapper.h:115:66: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

     reference dereference() const { return m_array->GetItem(m_idx); }

                                                                  ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/Wrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/Wrapper.o

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

In file included from src/Wrapper.cpp:1:0:

src/Wrapper.h: In member function ‘const boost::python::api::object& CJavascriptArray::ArrayIterator::dereference() const’:

src/Wrapper.h:115:66: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

     reference dereference() const { return m_array->GetItem(m_idx); }

                                                                  ^

src/Wrapper.cpp: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Boolean> CPythonObject::IndexedDeleter(uint32_t, const v8::AccessorInfo&)’:

src/Wrapper.cpp:256:25: warning: variable ‘value’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

   v8::Handle<v8::Value> value = IndexedGetter(index, info);

                         ^

src/Wrapper.cpp: In static member function ‘static void CPythonObject::SetupObjectTemplate(v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate>)’:

src/Wrapper.cpp:311:84: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Boolean> (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::AccessorInfo&)’ to ‘v8::NamedPropertyQuery {aka v8::Handle<v8::Integer> (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::AccessorInfo&)}’ [-fpermissive]

   clazz->SetNamedPropertyHandler(NamedGetter, NamedSetter, NamedQuery, NamedDeleter);

                                                                                    ^

In file included from src/Exception.h:6:0,

                 from src/Wrapper.h:8,

                 from src/Wrapper.cpp:1:

/usr/include/v8.h:2414:8: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetNamedPropertyHandler(v8::NamedPropertyGetter, v8::NamedPropertySetter, v8::NamedPropertyQuery, v8::NamedPropertyDeleter, v8::NamedPropertyEnumerator, v8::Handle<v8::Value>)’ [-fpermissive]

   void SetNamedPropertyHandler(NamedPropertyGetter getter,

        ^

src/Wrapper.cpp:312:94: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Boolean> (*)(uint32_t, const v8::AccessorInfo&) {aka v8::Handle<v8::Boolean> (*)(unsigned int, const v8::AccessorInfo&)}’ to ‘v8::IndexedPropertyQuery {aka v8::Handle<v8::Integer> (*)(unsigned int, const v8::AccessorInfo&)}’ [-fpermissive]

   clazz->SetIndexedPropertyHandler(IndexedGetter, IndexedSetter, IndexedQuery, IndexedDeleter);

                                                                                              ^

In file included from src/Exception.h:6:0,

                 from src/Wrapper.h:8,

                 from src/Wrapper.cpp:1:

/usr/include/v8.h:2437:8: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetIndexedPropertyHandler(v8::IndexedPropertyGetter, v8::IndexedPropertySetter, v8::IndexedPropertyQuery, v8::IndexedPropertyDeleter, v8::IndexedPropertyEnumerator, v8::Handle<v8::Value>)’ [-fpermissive]

   void SetIndexedPropertyHandler(IndexedPropertyGetter getter,

        ^

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pyv8/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-JQHgTo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pyv8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 235, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What's going wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: seems like you are not alone... see [this](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/issues/detail?id=228) forum. I cannot check it, but [this](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/issues/detail?id=132) post suggests you could fix it by specifying a different version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build from source using pip, you can run:

```
pip install svn+http://pyv8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

Or using [flier](https://github.com/flier/) (the author, it seems)'s [migrated github repository](https://github.com/flier/pyv8):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/flier/pyv8.git
```

Comment: I am getting errors. It doesn't work for `pip2` nor `pip3`. 

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, I had to remove some of the Ubuntu packages I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libv8-3.14.5 libv8-dev
```

Then, checkout PyV8 from subversion

```
$ svn checkout http://pyv8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ pyv8-read-only
```

The setup.py script took care of fetching and building the compatable version of V8:

```
$ cd pyv8-read-only
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: The googlecode svn isn't working for me. I've forked a pyv8 implementation by flier (the maintainer for the pyv8 pip package) and I'm working on changing it to use google's git repository (https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git)

Answer (score 2):

I was running into several different errors while trying to install PyV8. I didn't try to dig deeper into why exactly the different errors were happening. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit version.

I followed the following instructions

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev
sudo easy_install greenlet
sudo easy_install gevent
git clone https://github.com/buffer/pyv8.git
cd pyv8
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

and was able to install and use PyV8

This instruction was found here - https://github.com/buffer/thug/issues/170#issuecomment-225762492

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used this Guide for installing "PyV8" : [Importing PyV8 Engine into Python 2.7, the easy way](http://wikisecure.net/importing-pyv8-engine-into-python-v2-7-the-easy-way/) this was good for me :)

Comment: link is deeeaaaad

Comment: Found and fixed @Flint.

Answer (score 1):

To install PyV8 on a Debian based distro:

cd /usr/share

sudo git clone https://github.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries.git

cd pyv8-binaries/

sudo unzip pyv8-linux64.zip

sudo cp -a PyV8.py _PyV8.so /usr/bin