# I can't install with pip on Debian

Tags: python, pip, debian, pyv8

I have errors almost everytime I use pip (the package installer of Python) and I really don't manage to figure out how to fix them.

Below are the errors while trying to install pyv8 :

```
$ pip3 install pyv8
Collecting pyv8
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/fb/5c0512a373e3d0aad0b683f439e7bdd67f95a69e6473b76dc2cfdca2c43f/PyV8-0.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: pyv8
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyv8 ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-wmzf4xop/pyv8/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-h9c9ol37 --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  copying PyV8.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_PyV8' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/Exception.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/Exception.o
  In file included from src/Exception.cpp:1:
  src/Exception.h:6:10: fatal error: v8.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
   #include <v8.h>
            ^~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyv8
  Running setup.py clean for pyv8
Failed to build pyv8
Installing collected packages: pyv8
  Running setup.py install for pyv8 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-wmzf4xop/pyv8/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-wig6t3n9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    copying PyV8.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_PyV8' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/Exception.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/Exception.o
    In file included from src/Exception.cpp:1:
    src/Exception.h:6:10: fatal error: v8.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
     #include <v8.h>
              ^~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-wmzf4xop/pyv8/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-wig6t3n9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-wmzf4xop/pyv8/
```

Sorry if I can't give more precision

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184932/how-can-i-install-pyv8-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install pyv8 in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184932/how-can-i-install-pyv8-in-ubuntu-14-04)